# Access one database from multiple ORMs :: Caching issue

Tags: database, nhibernate, orm, caching

I know this is not a good idea and the best would be to let the applications talk Web Services. But I have a situation where the legacy application is accessing a database with an ORM and I need to access the same database from the new .net application using Fluent nHibernate.

So the question is what problems this will make and how to solve them?
I guess the main issue is the caching. I need to disable the caching on one of the applications (which would be the new app).

**So how can I disable caching in nHibernate?**

Is there anything else that should be careful about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching is not enabled by default in NHibernate.

One thing you need to consider is how to handle concurrent updates. Suggested read: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-optimistic